# possible bug in Flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, workflow, aws-sdk, amazon-swf

> Possible Bug:

When child B failed, handleStartChildWorkflowExecutionFailed method in GenericWorkflowClientImpl removed "OpenRequestInfo" from the scheduledExternalWorkflows map based on workflow id as a key. Since 5 child workflows have the same workflow id. So the map became empty once child B initialization failed. Therefore, the parent workflow cannot complete due to 4 child workflows requests are never able to close properly in handle* method.

Line 335 shows handleStartChildWorkflowExecutionFailed removes failed entry.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/worker/GenericWorkflowClientImpl.java#L335

Comment: Have you looked at the asynchronous stack trace of the stuck workflow? It is emitted using WorkflowReplayer.getAsynchronousThreadDumpAsString().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update2**: The issue is still not fixed :(.

**Update**: It might be that the bug was fixed by commit [0a183e02b29b06e9324b740af40daff9193c9290](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blame/master/aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/worker/ChildWorkflowDecisionStateMachine.java). Please verify.

It looks like a bug in the [DecisionsHelper](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/a51792ec9d34263c12de5231131b42bd7dc544d9/aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/worker/DecisionsHelper.java). It assumes that [DecisionId](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/a51792ec9d34263c12de5231131b42bd7dc544d9/aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/worker/DecisionId.java) is never reused as it is never removed from the *decisions* map. DecisionId is never reused for activities and lambdas, but as your discovered it is not always true for the child workflows :(. The workaround is to not reuse the child workflow id.

In your case I don't see a reason trying to schedule a child workflow with the same id as parent workflow has complete information about the state of the child workflow and can easily avoid it. BTW Have you considered using CronInvocationSchedule with AsyncScheduledExecutor as in [CronWithRety](https://www.codatlas.com/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/HEAD/src/samples/AwsFlowFramework/src/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/examples/cronwithretry/CronWithRetryWorkflowImpl.java) sample?

But this bug is nasty for cases when child workflow with the same id can be created by multiple instances of a parent workflow.

Comment: Yes, I understand the condition of triggering continue as new. My guess is also there are some async calls are still running so they are not completed. But, I also checked the workflow history events. It seems all child workflows are completed, which is different from what thread dump shows. See Workflow History Audit in Answers section.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! I have debugged for several scenarios. It only happens when the same Parent initiates the same child over and over again, which leads to child workflow initialization failed and hanging parent workflow. I updated my debugging result in main question section.

Comment: Unfortunately, our use case is fixed so I have to use that child workflow id all the time. Could you please give some advises on how to fix this bug ?

Comment: Just don't try to start the child workflow before the previous one is done. It is easy as you can chain the Promise from previous child workflow start to the next child workflow invocation.

Comment: I have checked this commit, which does not solve the issue. I still get the parent workflow failed caused by the lack of states in ChildStateMachine.java class. I have fixed this issue by providing the missing states and rebuilt the jar locally

Comment: I tried this to fix the issue. I have to fail the newly coming handler at line 163 of class "GenericWorkflowClientImpl" and throw a new Exception. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/worker/GenericWorkflowClientImpl.java#L163.

Comment: The drawback of this solution is that parent workflow history will not be able to have any failed child workflow events. But we did throw an exception so Flow code is able to catch that exception.

Comment: I don't understand the exception comment. Any unhandled exception from a child workflow is delivered to the parent independently of child id.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected ExternalTaskCancellationHandler doExecute(final     ExternalTaskCompletionHandle handle) throws Throwable {
    context.setCompletionHandle(handle);
    String workflowId = attributes.getWorkflowId();
    if (scheduledExternalWorkflows.containsKey(workflowId)) {
        WorkflowExecution workflowExecution = new WorkflowExecution();
        workflowExecution.setWorkflowId(workflowId);
        WorkflowType workflowType = attributes.getWorkflowType();

        long fakeEventId = -1;
        handle.fail(new StartChildWorkflowFailedException(fakeEventId, workflowExecution, workflowType,       StartChildWorkflowExecutionFailedCause.WORKFLOW_ALREADY_RUNNING.toString())    );

        return new ChildWorkflowCancellationHandler(workflowId, handle);
    }
        decisions.startChildWorkflowExecution(attributes);
        scheduledExternalWorkflows.put(workflowId, context);
        return new ChildWorkflowCancellationHandler(workflowId, handle);
    }
}
```

}

Updated the line 162 in this class:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/worker/GenericWorkflowClientImpl.java#L163